# What's a concise way of making a data frame with many multiples of the same vector as its columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I'm making a data frame out of `vector1` and 25 multiples of `vector2`, by doing the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(vector1,
vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2,
vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2,
vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2,
vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2,
vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2, vector2)
```

Is there a more concise way of coding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replicate` :

```
df1 <- cbind.data.frame(vector1, replicate(25, vector2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
data.frame(c(list(vector1),rep(list(vector2),25)))
```

Comment: Or with `rerun` `c(list(vector1), rerun(25, vector2))`

Comment: @akrun Wow, I learnt a new command from you! Thank you man :)